# Appending string to <T> to produce a new class name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, casting, type-conversion

How do I append string to a type name then pass it as another type? Here is an example:

```
 public T Get<T>(int id)
        {
           return dbAccess.Get<T>(id);
        }
```

If I call this method like

```
SomeObject.Get<Class1>(1234);
```

I would like to change `Class1` to be `Class1Data` by appending the string "Data" to any passed class, so the `dbAccess.Get` method would take the object as `Class1Data` as a conversion of `Class1`.

Comment: Generics are not meant to be used like that. Generics are merely a placeholder for an actual type which will be provided by the compiler at a later stage. On its face, the technique you are using is not suitable for a strongly typed language like C#. If you cannot avoid this, I recommend you go by the way what Jon is suggesting .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
public T Get<T>(int id)
    {
        var newTypeName = typeof(T).FullName + "Data";
        var newType = Type.GetType(newTypeName);
        var argTypes = new [] { newType };
        var method = GetType().GetMethod("Get");
        var typedMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(argTypes);
        return (T) typedMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { id });
    }
```

In case your XxxData object don't inherit from Xxx, you may want to do some automapping before returning the result.

Then you would have to replace the last line to:

```
        var dataResult = typedMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { id });
        var result = new T(); // You will have to add a new() constraint on generic parameter
        // Map your dataResult object's values onto the result object's values
        return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic parameter T is a compile time parameter.  In other words the compiler pre-processes your code at compile time and the types become fixed at this point.

So, you cannot at runtime change the type that is used for T.

One approach, if you have a constrained set of types, would be to set up the calls to each of them and then switch between them based on the string, e.g.

```
switch (str)
{
    case "":
        SomeObject.Get<Class1>(1234);
        break;

    case "Data":
        SomeObject.Get<Class1Data>(1234);
        break;
}
```

Or you could ditch generics completely and look at using reflection instead.

Comment: unfortunately this will not work, the reason behind the conversion is to automatically change business types to data types, every class passed to this call needs to be converted to the other data class name, all my business are the same as data classes with the string "Data" appended to it, Employee is EmployeeData and so on.

Comment: Why ditch generics, you can use them with reflection too (see my answer).

Comment: @Rene Wolferink, your answer makes sense now Maya has explained the full purpose of this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because all type parameters must be known at compile time. As long as both methods are generic there's nothing you can do about it.

Usually this kind of translation is performed by switching to reflection and runtime processing; for example, instead of the method's signature being `DbAccess.Get<T>(int)` it would have to be `DbAccess.Get(Type, int)`.