# Can we create List<user defined datatype> at runtime?

Tags: entity-framework, list, generics, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcjqgrid

Yes, i want to create a `List<T>` and my T is user defined data type i.e. POCO Class e.g. UserProfile.
**Why** : i am using [MvcJqGrid](https://github.com/robinvanderknaap/MvcJqGrid) and i want to write a generic code for creating the Json data so at runtime i come to know from which class(table) i need to get the data.

My Code

```
public ActionResult TestGrid() 
{
    string spname = Request.Params["storedprocedurename"]; //spname = UserProfile 
    // i get this from the post data of MvcJqGrid i.e. user when create a jqgrid, in 
    // a view defines the table/spname from where data gets loaded in grid.
    MyEntities _context = new MYEntities();            
    List<UserProfile> userProfiles = _context.UserProfiles.ToList<UserProfile>();
    // here some code to create a json data and return 
}
```

so this UserProfile i hardcoded here, what if i get RoleMaster(e.g.) in a Request.params 
so how can i achieve this.

**Configuration details** 
entityFramework  Version=5.0.0.0  database first approach
mvc 4 
MvcJqGrid 1.0.9
.net FrameWork 4.5

Comment: You might get some more info from a related question, in which a generic function was parameterized at runtime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397286/appending-string-to-t-to-produce-a-new-class-name/13397489#13397489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If spName is a string, you can get the type by:

```
Type genericType = Type.GetType(string.Format("YourNamespace.{0}", spName));
```

Then `userProfiles` below will be of type `List<UserProfile>` using the codes:

```
var method = _context.GetType().GetMember("Set")
                .Cast<MethodInfo>()
                .Where(x => x.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
                .FirstOrDefault();

var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(genericType);
dynamic invokeSet = genericMethod.Invoke(_context, null);

// this list will contain your List<UserProfile>
var userProfiles = Enumerable.ToList(invokeSet);
```

For more info:

1. [Reflection, Linq and DbSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253017/reflection-linq-dbset)

Comment: updated the answer. Now you will get the desired type - List<UserProfile>

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string spname = Request.Params["storedprocedurename"];
    Type t = typeof(MYEntities)
        .Assembly
        .GetType(string.Format("<namespace>.{0}", spname);
    dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    return View(ListData(instance));
}

private List<T> ListData<T>(T instance)
    where T : class
{
    MYEntities context = new MYEntities();
    return context.Set<T>().ToList();
}
```